# Access files in Google Shared Drive not owned by me

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to use an Apps script in Google drive to search for image files in company shared drive. The file list is held in a spreadsheet and the script searches for and either makes a copy of the file (if it's already a jpg or a png file) or exports a png file if it's a google drawing.

This is the code I have so far...

```
function load_list_of_images(course_workbook) {
  var image_list_sheet = course_workbook.getSheetByName("image_list");
  // Get list of image names from spreadsheet
  var list_of_images = [];
  var images = image_list_sheet.getRange(1,1,1000).getValues();
  for (var row in images) {
    for (var col in images[row]) {
      var image = images[row][col];
      if (image == "") {
        return(list_of_images);
      }
      list_of_images.push(image);
    }
  }
}

function download_google_images() {
  var course_workbook_name = "NAME"; // Title of spreadsheet with file list
  var dst_folder_id = "FOLDER_ID"; // ID of destination folder

  // There may be more than one!
  var course_workbooks = DriveApp.getFilesByName(course_workbook_name);
  // Try to access the spreadsheet
  try{
    var course_workbook_id = course_workbooks.next();
    Logger.log("Spreadsheet ID : " + course_workbook_id);    
  } catch(error) {
    Logger.log("Spreadsheet doesn't exist... exiting...");
    return(null);
  }
  var course_workbook = SpreadsheetApp.open(course_workbook_id);
  var list = load_list_of_images(course_workbook);
  // This will hold a list of missing images
  var missing = [];
  // What if the list is empty?
  if (list == null){
    Logger.log("Errr... no images to find - check the sheet!");
    return(null);
  }
  // Set up handle to destination folder
  var dst_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(dst_folder_id);

  // Now look for each image in the list
  for (var row in list){
    // Get the name of the image to look for
    var image_name = list[row];
    Logger.log("Looking for : " + image_name);
    // Get all the files which match this name
    // This line ONLY finds images that are owned by me
    // MOST of the images are owned by other users
    var image_exists = DriveApp.getFilesByName(image_name);
    // The list of images is empty
    if (!image_exists.hasNext()){
      Logger.log("  Can't find image : " + image_name);
      missing.push([image_name]);
    }
    // I found some images!
    else{
      while (image_exists.hasNext()){
        var image = image_exists.next()
        var drive_mime_type = image.getMimeType();
        // I'll tell you which type of file I've found
        Logger.log("  I've found a '" + drive_mime_type + "' file.");
        // Deal with file types
        switch (drive_mime_type) {
          // Existing JPG file
          case "image/jpeg":
            var already_exists = DriveApp.getFolderById(dst_folder_id).getFilesByName(image_name);
            if (!already_exists.hasNext()){
              Logger.log("  Creating image : " + image_name);          
              var copy = image.makeCopy(dst_folder);
            }
            else{
              Logger.log("  It's already in the destination so I won't create another one.");
            }
            break;
          // Existing PNG file
          case "image/png":
            var already_exists = DriveApp.getFolderById(dst_folder_id).getFilesByName(image_name);
            if (!already_exists.hasNext()){
              Logger.log("  Creating image : " + image_name);
              var copy = image.makeCopy(dst_folder);
            }
            else{
              Logger.log("  It's already in the destination so I won't create another one.");
            }
            break;
          // Google drawing - Convert to PNG!
          case "application/vnd.google-apps.drawing":
            var exportUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + image.getId() + "/export?mimeType=image/png";
            var urlFetchOptions = {
              headers: {Authorization : "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}
            }
            try{
              var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl, urlFetchOptions).getBlob();
            }
            catch(err){
              Logger.log("  There is an error getting the image : " + image_name);
              Logger.log(err);
              return(null);
            }
            var already_exists = DriveApp.getFolderById(dst_folder_id).getFilesByName(image_name + ".png");
            if (!already_exists.hasNext()){
              Logger.log("  Creating image : " + image_name);
              DriveApp.getFolderById(dst_folder_id).createFile(blob).setName(image_name + ".png");
            }
            else {
              Logger.log("  There is already a png version in the destination so I won't create another one.");
            }
            break;
          }
      } 
    }
  }
  // Populate the missing images list
  var missing_images_sheet = course_workbook.getSheetByName("missing_images");
  missing_images_sheet.getRange(1,1,1000).clear();
  var missing_images_range = missing_images_sheet.getRange(1,1,missing.length);
  missing_images_range.setValues(missing);
}
```

All the image files are in a Shared Google Drive. I'm a full member on all the drives. The behaviour at the moment is that ONLY files *owned by me* are located from the SHARED drive and copied into the destination folder whereas most of the images were created by another user of the drive.

How do I change the script so that it finds files owned by ANYONE?

The appscript.json file which is with the script looks like this...

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/London",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": []
  },
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata"
  ],
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your question. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about your current issue? And also, can you explain about your current script? And, when you run the script, does an error occur?

Comment: Thanks you for your response @tanaike - the files that the script tries to download are in a shared drive. The script will only download the files that I own but most of the files I want to download are owned by another user in the company - the script does not even find them. There are no errors.

Comment: I've added more comments to the script. It is this line... ```var image_exists = DriveApp.getFilesByName(image_name);``` which ONLY finds images owned by me but most of the images are owned by other users. How can I change the script so that it finds ALL files irrespective of owner?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, how about using Drive API instead of Drive service? When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

The main modification is as follows.

#### From:

```
var image_exists = DriveApp.getFilesByName(image_name);
```

#### To:

```
var image_exists = Drive.Files.list({corpora: "drive", driveId: "###DriveID###", includeItemsFromAllDrives: true, supportsAllDrives: true, maxResults: 1000, q: `title='${image_name}'`}).items;
```

#### Modified script:

In this case, please modify `download_google_images()` as follows. Please set your Drive ID of the shared Drive to `###DriveID###` of `var image_exists = Drive.Files.list({corpora: "drive", driveId: "###DriveID###", includeItemsFromAllDrives: true, supportsAllDrives: true, maxResults: 1000, q:` title='${image_name}'`}).items;`. And [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```
function download_google_images() {
  var course_workbook_name = "NAME"; // Title of spreadsheet with file list
  var dst_folder_id = "FOLDER_ID"; // ID of destination folder

  // There may be more than one!
  var course_workbooks = DriveApp.getFilesByName(course_workbook_name);
  // Try to access the spreadsheet
  try{
    var course_workbook_id = course_workbooks.next();
    Logger.log("Spreadsheet ID : " + course_workbook_id);    
  } catch(error) {
    Logger.log("Spreadsheet doesn't exist... exiting...");
    return(null);
  }
  var course_workbook = SpreadsheetApp.open(course_workbook_id);
  var list = load_list_of_images(course_workbook);
  // This will hold a list of missing images
  var missing = [];
  // What if the list is empty?
  if (list == null){
    Logger.log("Errr... no images to find - check the sheet!");
    return(null);
  }
  // Set up handle to destination folder
  var dst_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(dst_folder_id);

  // Now look for each image in the list
  for (var row in list){
    // Get the name of the image to look for
    var image_name = list[row];
    Logger.log("Looking for : " + image_name);
    // Get all the files which match this name
    // This line ONLY finds images that are owned by me
    // MOST of the images are owned by other users

    var image_exists = Drive.Files.list({corpora: "drive", driveId: "###DriveID###", includeItemsFromAllDrives: true, supportsAllDrives: true, maxResults: 1000, q: `title='${image_name}'`}).items;  // <--- Modified

    // The list of images is empty
    if (image_exists.length == 0) {  // <--- Modified
      Logger.log("  Can't find image : " + image_name);
      missing.push([image_name]);
    }
    // I found some images!
    else {
      image_exists.forEach(e => {  // <--- Modified
        var image = DriveApp.getFileById(e.id);  // <--- Modified
        var drive_mime_type = image.getMimeType();
        // I'll tell you which type of file I've found
        Logger.log("  I've found a '" + drive_mime_type + "' file.");
        // Deal with file types
        switch (drive_mime_type) {
          // Existing JPG file
          case "image/jpeg":
            var already_exists = DriveApp.getFolderById(dst_folder_id).getFilesByName(image_name);
            if (!already_exists.hasNext()) {
              Logger.log("  Creating image : " + image_name);
              var copy = image.makeCopy(dst_folder);
            }
            else {
              Logger.log("  It's already in the destination so I won't create another one.");
            }
            break;
          // Existing PNG file
          case "image/png":
            var already_exists = DriveApp.getFolderById(dst_folder_id).getFilesByName(image_name);
            if (!already_exists.hasNext()) {
              Logger.log("  Creating image : " + image_name);
              var copy = image.makeCopy(dst_folder);
            }
            else {
              Logger.log("  It's already in the destination so I won't create another one.");
            }
            break;
          // Google drawing - Convert to PNG!
          case "application/vnd.google-apps.drawing":
            var exportUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + image.getId() + "/export?mimeType=image/png";
            var urlFetchOptions = {
              headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() }
            }
            try {
              var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl, urlFetchOptions).getBlob();
            }
            catch (err) {
              Logger.log("  There is an error getting the image : " + image_name);
              Logger.log(err);
              return (null);
            }
            var already_exists = DriveApp.getFolderById(dst_folder_id).getFilesByName(image_name + ".png");
            if (!already_exists.hasNext()) {
              Logger.log("  Creating image : " + image_name);
              DriveApp.getFolderById(dst_folder_id).createFile(blob).setName(image_name + ".png");
            }
            else {
              Logger.log("  There is already a png version in the destination so I won't create another one.");
            }
            break;
        }
      });  // <--- Modified
    }
  }
  // Populate the missing images list
  var missing_images_sheet = course_workbook.getSheetByName("missing_images");
  missing_images_sheet.getRange(1,1,1000).clear();
  var missing_images_range = missing_images_sheet.getRange(1,1,missing.length);
  missing_images_range.setValues(missing);
}
```

#### Note:

- In this case, when you have no permission of reader or writer of the shared Drive, above modified script cannot be used. So please be careful this.
- In the current stage, it seems that the files in the shared Drive cannot be retrieved using `DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename)` with the filename. On the other hand, when the file ID is used, `DriveApp.getFileById(fileId)` returns the file object from the shared Drive. From this situation, I proposed to use the method of files.list in Drive API for retrieving the file metadata from the filename. This is from [Iamblichus's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65909714/access-files-in-google-shared-drive-not-owned-by-me/65915577?noredirect=1#comment116543987_65915577).

#### Reference:

- [Files: list of Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list)

Comment: Thank you for providing this answer. For the sake of completeness, I'd consider mentioning that the method the OP is using ([DriveApp.getFilesByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFilesByName(String))) can only retrieve files in the user's Drive, and that's probably the reason they're not retrieving some of the files.

Comment: @Iamblichus Thank you for your comment. From your comment, I could notice that I forgot to add the information. Now I added it. Could you please confirm it? Thank you for your always support.

Comment: Absolutely amazing - thank you! One more question - if there are a number of shared drives that the image could be in, can I just iterate through the Drive IDs or is there a way of specifying more than one drive it in the Drive.List method?

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for adding this additional explanation to your answer. @MarkMills I think you could set `corpora` to `allDrives` for this.

Comment: @Mark Mills Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I think that Iamblichus's comment can resolve it.

Comment: @Tanaike - that works PERFECTLY! You have taught me lots! THANK YOU!