# Google Scripts: Urlfetchapp with Youtube API having trouble uploading videos with different owners in a shared drive folder. Processing abandoned

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, youtube-api

I am currently trying to automate uploading videos from a shared drive folder to Youtube using the following [code from this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987147/how-upload-a-video-to-youtube-using-google-apps-script):

```
function upload() {
  var driveurl = `https://drive.google.com/file/d/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/view?usp=share_link`
  var match = driveurl.match(/([a-z0-9_-]{25,})[$/&?]/i).pop();
  var url = `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/`+match+`?alt=media`; 
  var title = "title";
  var description = "test";
  var topics = "TEST";
  var blob,mp4_fileId,part,requestResource,response;
  var options = {},snippet = {};

  /*
    You will need to create a GCP standard project and associate it with this Apps Script project-
    In the new code editor click the settings cog wheel and scroll down to:
    Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Project -
    You may get an error:
    In order to change your project, you will need to configure the OAuth consent screen. Configure your OAuth Consent details.
    
    And if you do not have a Google Workspace account then you wont be able to set up the GCP project as "INTERNAL"
    You will need to enable the Google Drive API and the YouTube API in the associated GCP project -
  */

  /*
    This code needs the file ID of the MP4 file in your Google Drive - 
    To get the file ID of an MP4 video file in Google Drive, right click the MP4 in your Google Drive
    and choose, "Get link"
    The link will look like this:
    https://drive.google.com/file/d/FILE_ID_IS_HERE/view?usp=sharing
    In the URL is the file ID
  */

  options = {
    "method" : "get",
    "headers" : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    "muteHttpExceptions":true
  }
  var video = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
 response = YouTube.Videos.insert({
            snippet:{
                title: title,
                description: description,
                tags: topics
            },
            status:{
              privacyStatus: "public",
            },
       },
       "snippet,status",
       video
   );
   Logger.log(JSON.stringify(response));    
Logger.log(response.id)
}
```

The code works great when I am the owner of the file. However, when I try and grab a file from another user in the same folder, the code no longer works. It tries to push a video to youtube but results in the error "Processing abandoned" visible in my youtube channel. If I copy the file and become the owner of the copy, it works fine so it is not something special with the specific video.

I thought of trying something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65909714/access-files-in-google-shared-drive-not-owned-by-me) The function Drive.File.get(ID) does not produce the correct object type i.e. it needs to be a blob but I cannot figure out how to get it to there. DriveApp.getFileById(match).getBlob() is my thought, but I have to wait till tomorrow to test due to hitting my upload limit for YouTube today and I'm not optimistic with the link provided.

It seems like there is some error associated with permissions, but I am not fully sure how to proceed to fix it. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, I apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. And, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current situation from `However, when I try and grab a file from another user in the same folder, the code no longer works.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? First, I would like to try to correctly understand your question. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike sorry about the unclear language. The code no longer works means that if another user owns the file, youtube throws a "Processing Abandoned" error. I was successfully able to overcome this by replacing ``` var video = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options)``` with ```DriveApp.getFileById(match).getBlob()```
I will answer my own question once the correct time has passed for SO to let me. On the other side, I have now learned that ```YouTube.Videos.insert``` has a 50MB upload limit that I need to figure out how to circumvent. Sigh, but thank you for the comment

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about the file size you want to upload?

Comment: The file size seems to have a limit over 0.05GB or 50MB for the ```DriveApp.getFileById(match).getBlob()``` method. The ```video = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options)``` method does not have this limit. I chatted with GAS support and they pointed to the problem being with the blob type for the object and that was causing the error on file size. Not really sure how to resolve it as Youtube.video.insert requires a blob type if fetched via Driveapp. And thank you for responding. It is always nice to have nice interactions with folks here

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About the limitation of 50 MB, I understand it. So, I asked your expected file size of the file you want to upload. I apologize for this.

Comment: Oh that is my fault, we have files that are no larger than 100MB. So <100MB for the file size. That is why this is frustrating! They're just barely larger than the limit!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that your file size is less than 100 MB. From this situation, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

From your following reply,

> we have files that are no larger than 100MB. So <100MB for the file size.

I understood that the file size of the files you want to upload is less than 100 MB.

In this case, it is required to upload it to YouTube with the resumable upload. In this case, I have already posted it on my blog. [Ref Author: me](https://tanaikech.github.io/2022/11/13/uploading-video-file-on-google-drive-to-youtube-with-resumable-upload-using-google-apps-script/) But, when I searched it in Stackoverflow, I couldn't find it. So, here, I would like to post it as an answer.

#### Sample script.

This sample script uses Drive API and YouTube API. So, [please enable them at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, please copy and paste the following sample script to the script editor of Google Apps Script.

In your showing script in your question, I think that `match` is the file ID.

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Please set the file ID of video file and the metadata for uploading it to YouTube.
  const fileId = "###";
  const metadata = {
    snippet: { description: "Upload sample.", title: "Sample uploaded video." },
    status: { privacyStatus: "private" },
  };

  // 1. Retrieve location.
  const headers = { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() };
  const url1 = encodeURI(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet,status"
  );
  const res1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url1, {
    headers,
    payload: JSON.stringify(metadata),
    contentType: "application/json",
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
  });
  if (res1.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    console.log(res1.getContentText());
    return;
  }
  const location = res1.getAllHeaders()["Location"];
  console.log("Got Location.");

  // 2. Calculate chunks.
  const chunkSize = 20971520; // 20 MB
  const { fileSize } = Drive.Files.get(fileId, {
    supportsAllDrives: true,
    fields: "fileSize",
  });
  const chunks = [...Array(Math.ceil(fileSize / chunkSize))].map((_, i, a) => [
    i * chunkSize,
    i == a.length - 1 ? fileSize - 1 : (i + 1) * chunkSize - 1,
  ]);
  console.log("Calculated chunk data.");

  // 3. Retrieve chunks from Google Drive with the partial download and uploading chunks to YouTube with the resumable upload.
  const url2 = `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${fileId}?alt=media&supportsAllDrives=true`;
  let res2;
  const len = chunks.length;
  let responseObject;
  chunks.forEach((e, i) => {
    console.log(`Now... ${i + 1}/${len}`);
    const params2 = {
      headers: {
        authorization: headers.authorization,
        range: `bytes=${e[0]}-${e[1]}`,
      },
    };
    res2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, params2).getContent();
    const params3 = {
      headers: { "Content-Range": `bytes ${e[0]}-${e[1]}/${fileSize}` },
      payload: res2,
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
    };
    console.log("Downloaded a chunk, and upload a chunk.");
    const res3 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(location, params3);
    const statusCode = res3.getResponseCode();
    if (statusCode == 200) {
      console.log("Done.");
      // console.log(res3.getContentText());
      responseObject = JSON.parse(res3.getContentText());
    } else if (statusCode == 308) {
      console.log("Upload the next chunk.");
      res2.splice(0, res2.length);
    } else {
      throw new Error(res3.getContentText());
    }
  });
  // console.log(responseObject); // Here, you can retrieve the response object.
  console.log(responseObject.id); // Here, you can retrieve the video ID.

  // Please don't remove the following comment line. This comment line is important for running this script.
  // YouTube.Videos.insert(); // This is used for automatically detecting the scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube" with the script editor.
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run, you can see the following process in the log.

```
Got Location.
Calculated chunk data.
Now... 1/10
Downloaded a chunk, and upload a chunk.
Upload the next chunk.
Now... 2/10
Downloaded a chunk, and upload a chunk.
Upload the next chunk.
Now... 3/10
Downloaded a chunk, and upload a chunk.
Upload the next chunk.
Now... 4/10
Downloaded a chunk, and upload a chunk.
Upload the next chunk.
Now... 5/10
Downloaded a chunk, and upload a chunk.
Upload the next chunk.
Now... 6/10
Downloaded a chunk, and upload a chunk.
Upload the next chunk.
Now... 7/10
Downloaded a chunk, and upload a chunk.
Upload the next chunk.
Now... 8/10
Downloaded a chunk, and upload a chunk.
Upload the next chunk.
Now... 9/10
Downloaded a chunk, and upload a chunk.
Upload the next chunk.
Now... 10/10
Downloaded a chunk, and upload a chunk.
Done.
{
  "kind": "youtube#video",
  "etag": "###",
  "id": "###",
  "snippet": {,,,},
  "status": {,,,}
}
```

#### IMPORTANT

- In this sample script, the chunk size is 20 MB as a sample. You can modify this. But, when this size is large, an error might occur. Please be careful about this.
- If you have no YouTube channel, you cannot upload the video file.
- When your account is not confirmed by Google side, video data of more than 15 minutes cannot be uploaded. Please be careful about this.
- In the current stage, the maximum execution time of Google Apps Script is 6 minutes. So, when you want to upload a large video data, the data might not be able to be completely uploaded, because of the maximum execution time. Please be careful about this.

  - If you want to upload the video data with more large size, I think that you can achieve it by executing the script with the time-driven trigger. But, in this case, it is required to modify the above script. Please be careful about this. In this post, the simple sample script is introduced.
  - I confirmed that when I tested 100 MB, no error occurs. So, about your situation, I thought that this script can be used.

#### References

- [Curl Command Uploading Video File to YouTube with Resumable Upload using YouTube API](http://localhost:1313/2022/11/11/curl-command-uploading-video-file-to-youtube-with-resumable-upload-using-youtube-api/)
- [Resumable Uploads](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol)

Comment: This worked amazingly. I wish I had found your blog post when I was working on this before. Thank you for the successful answer it will be marked. 

I will ask one more question. I am wondering if it is possible to return the id of the video after the process is complete?

In the original code this was easy with ```var response = YouTube.Videos.insert``` followed by ```response.id``` but in this case the video.insert function is within the comment and no longer an object. I do see the ID in the execution log, but am not sure how to pull the ID.

Comment: @Andrewncf Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question of `I am wondering if it is possible to return the id of the video after the process is complete?`, I updated my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay on accepting the answer, I was at my Youtube API quota limit and could not test until now. For the application I am using, [it requires a return statement] (https://support.google.com/appsheet/answer/12309564?hl=en). I tried to simple use ```return console.log(responseObject.id);``` but no luck there. Same with ```var outputID = console.log(responseObject.id); return outputID``` Any thoughts? I apologize as I am used to more declarative formats so I am not sure if there is a better way?
Regardless, thank you for the initial help. It was amazing!!!!!!

Comment: @Andrewncf Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `I tried to simple use return console.log(responseObject.id); but no luck there.`, unfortunately, when I tested my script, the metadata of the uploaded video and the video ID can be seen at `console.log(responseObject)` and `console.log(responseObject.id)`. I apologize for this. I think that this is due to my poor skill. I apologize for this. But, I would like to support you. So, I would like to try to correctly replicate your situation. When I could correctly replicate it, I would like to think of a solution.

Comment: @Andrewncf I have to apologize for my poor skill, again. Although I tested my propsoed script several times, I can confirm the returned metadata and video ID. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate `I tried to simple use return console.log(responseObject.id); but no luck there.`. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again. But, I would like to support you. So, I would like to try to correctly replicate `I tried to simple use return console.log(responseObject.id); but no luck there.`.

Comment: @Andrewncf Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `I would like to assign the id to a constant (or object) to build the url youtube.com/embed{ID} so that the external application can use the youtube video that was uploaded. return responseObject.id.toString()`, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. And also, I cannot understand whether your 2nd question was resolved. I think that this is due to my very poor English skill. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Andrewncf I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your various questions soon. I think that I have to study English more.

Comment: I am sorry, I will try to explain one last time and if it is not clear it is okay. you have helped so much and I wish I could show my appreciation. Normally my application calls the function like this:

```function add(a){
var answer = a+2
return answer
}```
When the website calls the script with the value a=2 it returns the user with the answer 4
I am just not sure how this works with ```console.log(responseObject.id)```
That was why I had tried ```return console.log(responseObject.id)``` but the external application did not receive the return value.

Comment: I am more than happy to accept your answer and keep trying on my own. You really have helped me so much and I am so thankful. Your english has been really good in communications, I really appreciate you so much here

Comment: @Andrewncf Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your new question. I'm worried that I might trouble you because I cannot resolve your various questions soon. So, in this case, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question. By this, it will help a lot of users think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'd be glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @Andrewncf Thank you for replying. When you posted it as a new question, I would like to try to understand it again.

Comment: I was actually able to solve my issue by writing a separate function that finds the id of the newest video on my channel and returns that id back to my original application. You did all the hard work and thank you again for helping me so much.
[This was what i used to get the id's, the middle option retrieve uploads](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/youtube)

Comment: @Andrewncf Thank you for replying. I'm glad your new question was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the code:
`var video = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);`
to:
`var video = DriveApp.getFileById(match).getBlob()` solves the issue completely. However, I have learned there is a 50MB file size upload limit using this process, which seems small for videos. However, if anyone is trying to upload any videos smaller than that to their channel. I cleaned up the code and this works well

```
function upload4() {
  var driveurl = `https://drive.google.com/file/d/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA?usp=share_link`
  var match = driveurl.match(/([a-z0-9_-]{25,})[$/&?]/i).pop();
  var title = "title";
  var description = "test";
  var topics = "TEST";
  var video = DriveApp.getFileById(match).getBlob();
  var response = YouTube.Videos.insert({
            snippet:{
                title: title,
                description: description,
                tags: topics
            },
            status:{
              privacyStatus: "private",
            },
       },
       "snippet,status",
       video
   );
   Logger.log(JSON.stringify(response));    
Logger.log(response.id)
}
```